# how can i hide the extra console log

Tags: reactjs, console

I've searched several forums but couldn't find the complete solution.
A dynamically changing console log is coming.
[image]

'VM' here is constantly changing not a fixed value

my component is not rendering twice how can i fix this problem thanks

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Problem solved when I saved my app file from react-stricts in indexjs thx